# A calculator using tkinter library

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

I want to have a calculator with 4 buttons and 2 entry. What is my problem? I don't know how to fix that it can't multiply sequence by non-int of type `str` nor can't multiply `entry * entry`.

Also I don't know where is my output and how use that.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

#the environment

calc=tk.Tk()
calc.title("Calculator")

#-------------------------------------
#lables and their data entry
tk.Label(calc,text="enter your first number:").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(calc,text="enter your second number:").grid(row=1)
e1=tk.Entry(calc)
e2=tk.Entry(calc)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
x1=e1.get()
x2=e2.get()
tk.Label(calc,text="your result is:").grid(row=3)

# a free variable for get output,is this really need?
lbl=list()
#---------------------------

#the functions but my entry are entry type
def prod():
    lbl=print(x1*x2)

def div():
    lbl=print(x1/x2)

def sum():
     lbl=print(x1+x2)

def min():
    lbl=print(x1-x2)
#-------------------------------


#buttons and function in them as a command
 btn1=tk.Button(calc,text="*",command=prod()).grid(row=0,column=2)
 btn2=tk.Button(calc,text="/",command=div()).grid(row=1,column=2)
 btn3=tk.Button(calc,text="+",command=sum()).grid(row=2,column=2)
 btn4=tk.Button(calc,text="-",command=min()).grid(row=3,column=2)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

#The answer which i need it
 print("your answer is:")



 calc.mainloop()
```

Comment: First you need to fix your indentation, this is critical in Python.

Comment: `command=prod()` should be `command=prod`, and similar for all the other buttons.

Comment: Are you confident that the numbers the user is entering have been converted to integers? If not, then they are within string form, based upon my examination of your program; convert the retrieved numbers to integers prior to multiplying them. this should work successfully. If you require assistance, provide further details and I may be able to help.

Comment: @martineau: your comment is a bit confusing - you don't have to use `textvariable` in order to get data from an `Entry` widget. You can do that without a textvariable.

Comment: @Bryan: I'm sure you're right. I was just going by what [this documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190530085656id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) says (see the part about the `textvariable` option). I will delete the misleading comment (although doing what is says would work).

Comment: @martineau: that documentation is wrong. The `Entry` widget has a documented `get` method for getting the data out of the widget. Usually that is sufficient. Using a textvariable is fine, but it adds an extra object to maintain with no real added value unless you're using some of the special features provided by the textvariable (tracing, and sharing between widgets).

Comment: @Bryan: Thanks for the clarification. You comments and answer are first rate. When's that book on tkinter programming you're writing coming out? `;¬)`

Comment: Hi i have a question,what can i do for next project. which can improve my coding.Could you give an example or any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GUI programming, you need to get the value of widgets at the time you need them, not at the time you create them.

Also, widgets return string values. If you are doing math on them, you need to convert them to numbers first.

If you want to display the result in the window, you can update a label widget with the `configure` method

For example, your `prod` definition could look something like this:

```
def prod():
    x1 = int(e1.get())
    x2 = int(e2.get())
    result = x1 * x2
    result_label.configure(text=str(result))
```

You then need to do two other things. First, you need to create the label for the result, and store the widget in a variable. To do that you must separate the creation of the widget from the layout since calling `grid` would cause the variable to be set to `None`

```
result_label = tk.Label(calc,text="your result is:")
result_label.grid(row=3)
```

Finally, your buttons need to be given a reference to the function. What you're currently doing is calling the function and assigning the result to the `command` attribute.

Your button should look like the following. Notice that `prod` does not have `()` after it:

```
btn1 = tk.Button(calc, text="*", command=prod)
...
btn1.grid(row=0,column=2)
```

On a side note, I think that for all widgets with a common parent, grouping all widget creation code together and then all calls to `grid` or `pack` together makes the code easier to read, easier to maintain, and easier to visualize.

For example:

```
btn1 = tk.Button(...)
btn2 = tk.Button(...)
btn3 = tk.Button(...)
btn4 = tk.Button(...)

btn1.grid(row=0,column=2)
btn2.grid(row=1,column=2)
btn3.grid(row=2,column=2)
btn4.grid(row=3,column=2)
```